# MBP 2015 with Trim enabled by default?

Tags: trim

Since MBP early 2015 use PCIe SSD, do I still need to enable Trim through Chameleon SSD Optimizer or Trim Enabler?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Apple-branded SSD (i.e. it came with your Laptop and you did not install it yourself), there is no need to enable TRIM manually.